# Is it necessary to use listview for showing json array?

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

I'm just a beginner and recently saw various tutorial over using `json` in android. All the videos and tutorials i saw were using `ListView` for displaying Json array item.

I want to know can't we use any other apart from list view for showing json array. Like a  `Linearlayout` having various `textviews` each for a json item. 
Please answer i really want to know.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself, and then post here if it works with `TextView` or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you like to display the content. A `ListView` or any other view using an `Adapter` has certain advantages if you don't know how many array elements there are in advance.

Comment: I have a layout file (not main layout) which have a linear layout and four textviews in it. How to display json array values in them.

Comment: You have to do that manually. Put array element 1 into text view 1 and so on.